# I cant get my searching program to work on react

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and I am currently working on this simple program that searches from github api and returns a list of repositorys names and urls. I cant get it to work. The earlier version worked and i  could fetch up to five different names and urls. Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState('[]');
  const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState('')
  const fetchData = () => {
    fetch('https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=' + keyword)
    .then(response => {
      if (response.status !== 200) {
        throw new Error('Response status not ok');
      }
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(resData => {
      setItems(resData.data);
    })
  };
  const inputChanged = (event) => {
    setKeyword(event.target.value);
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h4>Repositories</h4>
      <input placeholder="Keyword" value={keyword} onChange={inputChanged} />
      <button onClick={fetchData}>Search</button>
      <h4>Name</h4>
      <ul>{items.full_name} {items.url}</ul>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

The searchbar works fine but after that it doesnt do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues here:

1. You defined `'[]'` initial value for your `items`, but it should be just `const [items, setItems] = useState([]);`
2. `items` is an array, so you should iterate using `.map` to render the items: `{items.map(item => <li key={item.url}>{item.full_name} {item.url}.</li>)}`

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState('')
  const fetchData = () => {
    fetch('https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=' + keyword)
    .then(response => {
      if (response.status !== 200) {
        throw new Error('Response status not ok');
      }
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(resData => {
      setItems(resData.items);
    })
  };
  const inputChanged = (event) => {
    setKeyword(event.target.value);
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h4>Repositories</h4>
      <input placeholder="Keyword" value={keyword} onChange={inputChanged} />
      <button onClick={fetchData}>Search</button>
      <h4>Name</h4>
      <ul>{items.map(item => <li key={item.url}>{item.full_name} {item.url}.</li>)}</ul>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks this was in depth and good answer I understood my mistakes!

Answer (score 0):

I think you might've made a mistake in your naming `setItems(resData.data);`.

Looks like it should be `setItems(resData.items);` instead.

You also need to map through your data once it's been fetched.

```
<ul>
  {items.map((item) => (
    <li>
      {item.full_name} {item.url}
    </li>
  ))}
</ul>
```

You also have set your initial item value as `"[]"`, which should be `[]`. `"[]"` is a string and cannot be iterated over.